# phonegap - deviceready event works but resume/online/offline event don't work

Tags: android, iphone, events, cordova

Im using an iframe to display an external url in my app, but if the internet or the website is no longer available i want to display an error message. In my code I'm using the deviceready/resume/online/offline events.
However my problem is that the deviceready event seems to fire and calls the other methods that I've defined but the other events don't seem to be firing(working). So if the internet or website is suddenly no longer available the iframe doesn't get refreshed and just stays on the same page/image - from a users point of view they don't know whats happening.

The following is some of my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.0.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


            function onload() 

            {

                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            }


            function onDeviceReady() 

            {

                document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

                document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

                document.addEventListener("offline", onoffline, false);

                document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

                checkUrl();

            }


            function onPause() {

              //code for the pause function     

            }

            function onResume()

            {

                   checkUrl();

            }


            function onoffline()

            {

               //display error message

            }


            function onOnline()

            {

                checkUrl();

            }


            function checkUrl()

            {

               //code to check the url is valid

                alert("checkur");

             }


            function onerror()

          {

                //display error message

           }                


          </script>

        </head>


<body onload="onload()">

    <div id="divFrameHolder" style="visibility:hidden;" scroll="no">

        <iframe allowtransparency src="http://www.XXXXX.com" id="iframe"width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" onerror="onerror();" style="text-align:center;" >

        </iframe>

    </div> 


</body>
```

In using cordova-1.6.0 - I'm getting the same issue on both android and iPhone

This has been driving me mad for ages, since one event is working i would have thought other event should work as well.
I would really appreciate any help/advice you might have.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas, please??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap events online/offline not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160866/phonegap-events-online-offline-not-working)