# cordova online/offline events not firing in android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I want to listen, when my device goes offline/online in my Cordova app, but I am unable to achieve it. I could see other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160866/phonegap-events-online-offline-not-working) here in SO,  with the same topic, but none are resolved. I tried as said in the Cordova [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online).

This is what I did. I created a new Cordova android project using CLI (btw I'm using Cordova 3.4), then added  'org.apache.cordova.network-information' plugin as below.

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

My config file has entry as below.

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

And my AndroidManifest file has the below entries.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My JS code is below.

```
initialize: function() {
    //alert('initialise');
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
onDeviceReady: function() {
    alert('device ready');
    document.addEventListener('online', this.onDeviceOnline, false);
    document.addEventListener('offline', this.onDeviceOffline, false);
},

onDeviceOnline: function() {
    alert('onDeviceOnline');
},

onDeviceOffline: function() {
    alert('onDeviceOffline');
}
```

It always comes to device ready, but never comes to online/offline event handlers when I connect/disconnect my wi-fi (and cellular data as well).

When I call below method it alerts the connection type correctly.So I know my plugin installation was successful.

```
function checkConnection() {
alert('checking connection');
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
```

}

Please help me on this. I'm stuck on this issue for some time now.

Thanks

Comment: Try changing `this.onDeviceOnline` in the listener to `app.onDeviceOnline` (or whatever the parent is). The reason is that at the point when the event is fired, it has no reference to what `this` was when the listener was set.